# node.js совместно с nginx

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, nginx

Нужно настроить совместную работу с nginx, т.е. nginx выступает в качестве прокси 8001 порта и отдает node.js приложение. Как в nginx запретить доступ к приложению с 8001 порта и оставить только доступ по `server_name`?

nginx

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name nodejs.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`
`proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Answer (score 4):

**`nginx` за это не отвечает.**

Можно запереть фаерволом, а можно на стороне NodeJS слушать **только локальную петлю**.

У вас где-то есть строчка вида `app.listen(8081)`? На самом деле это синоним `app.listen(8081, '0.0.0.0')`, он слушает **все сетевые интерфейсы**.

А можно сделать так: `app.listen(8081, 'localhost')`, и он будет недоступен по всем интерфейсам, **кроме локальной петли**, через которую `nginx` как раз проксирует запросы.

Comment: Спасибо, осталось понять как это сделать в sailsjs, способа изменить пока не вижу

Comment: @JILeXanDR ищите, где указывается порт, рядом должно быть указание bind address.